# Receiving 404 error from WCF Web API (Put operation)

Tags: http-status-code-404, put, wcf-web-api

I created a rest svc using WCF Web API. My GET Requests work just fine but i can't seem to get PUT requests to work. I keep getting 404 errors like the resource isn't there but it is.

**Server Code:**

```
    <WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="WebMaint", Method:="Put")>
Public Function WebMaintPut(ByVal entries As HttpRequestMessage(Of IList(Of WebMaint))) As HttpResponseMessage(Of WebMaint)
    Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage(Of WebMaint)(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    Using scope = New TransactionScope()
        entries.Content.ReadAs(Of IList(Of WebMaint)).AsParallel().ForAll(Sub(entry)
                                                                              _repos.Update(entry)
                                                                          End Sub)
        scope.Complete()
    End Using

    Return response
End Function
```

**Host Code:**

```
Public Sub New()
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(Sub(x)
                                 x.For(Of IWebMaintRepository)().Use(Of WebMaintRepository).Ctor(Of String).Is(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Dev").ConnectionString)
                             End Sub)
    _host = New HttpServiceHost(ObjectFactory.GetInstance(Of WebMaintResource), "http://localhost:8000/REST/")
    _host.Open()
End Sub
```

**Client Code:**

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Dim Content = New ObjectContent(Of IList(Of WebMaint))(_WebMaint)
       Dim response = client.Put(New Uri("http://localhost:8000/REST/WebMaint/"), Content)
        Debug.Print(response.StatusCode.ToString())
    End Using
End Sub
```

**PUT Request:**

```
PUT http://localhost:8000/REST/WebMaint/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Length: 592
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfWebMaint xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><WebMaint><WebMaintenanceID>1</WebMaintenanceID><Maintenance>true</Maintenance><WebSystemId>1</WebSystemId><WebMsgId>4</WebMsgId></WebMaint><WebMaint><WebMaintenanceID>2</WebMaintenanceID><Maintenance>true</Maintenance><WebSystemId>2</WebSystemId><WebMsgId>3</WebMsgId></WebMaint><WebMaint><WebMaintenanceID>3</WebMaintenanceID><Maintenance>true</Maintenance><WebSystemId>3</WebSystemId><WebMsgId>2</WebMsgId></WebMaint></ArrayOfWebMaint>
```

**PUT Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 19:31:43 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Endpoint not found.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was in the following line:

```
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="WebMaint", Method:="Put")>
```

Believe it or not the "method" parameter is *case sensitive*. Changing it to :
`<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="WebMaint", Method:="PUT")>` fixed the problem. I think there should be a better solution than just to receive an http 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

I dunno, but did you try also PUT instead of Put in the WebInvoke Attribute? (Sounds awkward but it's a Preview so it might be possible)

Did you try using List instead of IList?

Another possiblity is you may need to set the Content-Type in your request to text/xml explicitily.

If you're hosting on IIS (Express) you need to [enable PUT and DELETE](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx) as they're disabled by default.